# Publish Postgres changes to RabbitMQ?

Tags: postgresql, rabbitmq

I'm looking for a plugin/extension to publish events to RabbitMQ whenever a new row is added to Postgres.

I found couple of plugins like pgsql-listen-exchange, pg_amqp. but both of them are not working and dead as per git.

Aprt from these i found outbox pattern frameworks, but i need some kind of plugin/extension instead of application/framework.

Thanks.